# How to load JS for specific screen size using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: javascript

I need a option so that when I am adding some script using wp_enqueue_script it should load for specific screen size. Like when the screen size will be below 768px the script will not load.

I am using something like this for now.....

```
if(!wp_is_mobile()){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpm_animation_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animation.css', array(), '1.1', false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'uikit.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/uikit.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.4.0', true );
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks
Sabbir

Comment: PHP can't tell what the size of a screen is beforehand. Detecting mobiles also falls apart when you consider that browser windows can be resized. What you're trying to do will also fail when you deploy caching plugins

Answer (score -1):

At this point I can not think of a way to do what you ask in php (maybe in javascript), but perhaps approaching the problem differently, can serve you detect the mobile device in a better way using mobile-detect[1], wp_is_mobile() as it is very basic, only detects if mobile, but does not distinguish between  phones or tablets.

And there is already a plugin for wordpress[2], and this library have a lot examples[3]

1. https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect
2. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/
3. https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples

Comment: I figured it out using https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect. The same php class was used within this WordPress Plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/